# Firebase query by child value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My structure is like

```
2017511
   UcQefEaHJG6fteGsbsiaWjQ60d9Q62
     value1: 50
     value2: 1200
     value3: "blabla" 
   AcQefEaHJG6fteGsbsiaWjQ60d9Q62
     value1: 55
     value2: 2200
     value3: "balabla" 
   BcQefEaHJG6fteGsbsiaWjQ60d9Q62
     value1: 20
     value2: 500
     value3: "blabala"
```

I am trying to get the value 3 of top 10 highest value 2
I tried something like this but it screws up when new child added or any value changed

```
$("#myList").html("");
firebase.database()
  .ref('/2017511')
  .limitToLast(2)
  .orderByChild("value2")
  .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val().value3 + " "+ snapshot.val().value2);
      $("#myList").prepend("<p>"+ snapshot.val().value2 + " "+ snapshot.val().value3 +"<p><br>");
  })
```

I tried this, it works fine at first but if I run function again it just paste same values in every column...

```
function yenile(){
firebase.database().ref('/'+today).orderByChild("esita").limitToLast(1).once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
$("#bugun1").html(snapshot.val().username + " (" + (snapshot.val().esita).toFixed(0) + ")");
});
firebase.database().ref('/'+today).orderByChild("esita").limitToLast(2).once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
$("#bugun2").html(snapshot.val().username + " (" + (snapshot.val().esita).toFixed(0) + ")");
});
firebase.database().ref('/'+today).orderByChild("esita").limitToLast(3).once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
$("#bugun3").html(snapshot.val().username + " (" + (snapshot.val().esita).toFixed(0) + ")");
});
firebase.database().ref('/'+today).orderByChild("esita").limitToLast(4).once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
$("#bugun4").html(snapshot.val().username + " (" + (snapshot.val().esita).toFixed(0) + ")");
});
firebase.database().ref('/'+today).orderByChild("esita").limitToLast(5).once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
$("#bugun5").html(snapshot.val().username + " (" + (snapshot.val().esita).toFixed(0) + ")");
});
firebase.database().ref('/'+today).orderByChild("esita").limitToLast(6).once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
$("#bugun6").html(snapshot.val().username + " (" + (snapshot.val().esita).toFixed(0) + ")");
});
firebase.database().ref('/'+today).orderByChild("esita").limitToLast(7).once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
$("#bugun7").html(snapshot.val().username + " (" + (snapshot.val().esita).toFixed(0) + ")");
});
firebase.database().ref('/'+today).orderByChild("esita").limitToLast(8).once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
$("#bugun8").html(snapshot.val().username + " (" + (snapshot.val().esita).toFixed(0) + ")");
});
firebase.database().ref('/'+today).orderByChild("esita").limitToLast(9).once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
$("#bugun9").html(snapshot.val().username + " (" + (snapshot.val().esita).toFixed(0) + ")");
});
firebase.database().ref('/'+today).orderByChild("esita").limitToLast(10).once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
$("#bugun10").html(snapshot.val().username + " (" + (snapshot.val().esita).toFixed(0) + ")");
});
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong?

Comment: I am actually trying to show real time leaderboard but its not updating, and just prepend on already written data...

Comment: That last bit of code definitely won't help. Please stick to a single [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it's quite useful). Is there any way you can reproduce the behavior in a jsbin, so that I can look at it?

Comment: Yeah even I was not sure about using it but can not find a solution... just need to show top 10 should not been that hard :@

Comment: YESS SOLVED IT

function yenile(){
var i = 10
firebase.database().ref('/'+today).orderByChild("esita").limitToLast(5).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
$("#bugun"+i).html(snapshot.val().username + " (" + (snapshot.val().esita) + ")");
i -= 1;
});
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OP confirmed below worked.

```
function yenile(){ 
   var i = 10 
   firebase.database().ref('/'+today).orderByChild("esita").lim‌​itToLast(5).on("chil‌​d_added", function(snapshot) { 
        $("#bugun"+i).html(snapshot.val().username 
         + " (" + (snapshot.val().esita) + ")"); i -= 1; }); 
}
```